# What rule does 'apply (rule)' or 'proof' use?

Tags: isabelle

When I use `apply (rule)` in an apply-script, typically an appropriate rule is selected. The same holds for `proof` in structured proofs. Where can I learn/lookup the name of the rule that was used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using `rule_trace` as follows:

```
lemma "a ∧ b"
  using [[rule_trace]]
  apply rule
```

which will display in the output:

```
rules:
  ?P ⟹ ?Q ⟹ ?P ∧ ?Q
  ?P ⟹ ?Q ⟹ ?P ∧ ?Q 
proof (prove): step 2

goal (2 subgoals):
 1. a
 2. b
```

If the names of the rules are needed, you can then try using `find_theorems`; I'm not sure if they can be directly determined.

Answer (score 3):

Everything that is declared as `Pure.intro`/`intro`/`iff` (or one of its `?` or `!` variants) is considered as default introduction rule (i.e., if no current facts are chained in). Similarly, everything that is declared as `Pure.elim`/`elim`/`iff` is considered as default elimination rule (i.e., if current facts are chained in). Usually later declarations take precedence over earlier ones (at least if the same kind of declaration is used... mixing, e.g., `Pure.intro?` with `intro`, etc., might turn out differently).

However, this just answers what kind of rules are considered in principle. I don't know a way to directly find out which rule was applied. But it is relatively straight-forward to find the correct rule by `find_theorems intro` directly above the line you were wondering about. E.g.,

```
lemma "A & B"
find_theorems intro
proof
```

will show you all rules that could be applied as introduction rule to the goal `A & B`. One of them is the default rule applied by `proof` (you will recognize it by the subgoals you obtained).

For elimination rules you can use, e.g.,

```
lemma assumes "A | B" shows "P"
using assms
find_theorems elim
proof
```

Answer (score 3):

The other answers already tell you how to determine which lemmas are applied by `rule`. Note that `proof` does not call the `rule`, but the method `default`. Most of the time, `default` does the same as `rule`, but e.g. to prove a locale predicate it calls `unfold_locales`.

I don't know of any method to see what actually happens there.